# SQL WHERE statement after a JOIN with a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select some data, I'm joining 3 tables together, but one of the joins has a where statement. Once I have done the joins I need to add another where statement to select a date range and a location. I am getting an error on the second WHERE clause.

```
  SELECT a.[ID]
      ,a.[item_no]
      ,a.[qty]
  FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[details] AS a


  INNER JOIN [MYDB].[dbo].[delivery] AS b
  ON a.[item_no] = b.[item_no]
  INNER JOIN [MYDB].[dbo].[options] AS c
  ON a.[number] = c.[number] 
  WHERE a.[item_no] = c.[item_no]

WHERE b.[destination] = 'my destination'
AND b.[date] BETWEEN '2018-10-14' AND '2018-10-15'
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: When you get an error you should post it in your question, you have two solutions, one is to add the conditions to ON or add it to the last WHERE with another AND.

Comment: I would advise getting used to adding to the `ON` with an `AND`. The results can be different, but if you're narrowing down a `JOIN`, more often than not it's the `JOIN` you are thinking about, not the other tables in other `JOIN`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of answers posted already that will help you fix your code, but I wanted to explicitly address the misunderstanding that lead to the problem you're having. In your question, you said:

> ...one of the joins has a where statement.

But that's not correct. The `WHERE` clause is a part of the `SELECT` statement, not a part of the `JOIN`.

Broadly speaking, the SQL engine starts interpreting your query by looking at the `FROM` clause. Essentially, it starts by asking where your data will be coming from. Your `FROM` clause includes your base table, `[MYDB].[dbo].[details]`, plus any additional tables you're joining to. The `ON` criteria of your `JOIN` tells the engine which fields in the tables have corresponding data points. In the case of an `INNER JOIN`, this can have the effect of restricting the resulting data set, which is also the effect of a `WHERE` clause, but the filtering that results from the `JOIN` happens at the beginning of the query, when the engine is pulling the data into memory that your query will be manipulating.

*After* that initial data set is built, the engine reads the `WHERE` clause and applies any filters specified there.

Here's the MSDN discussion on the [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement).

You can specify multiple `ON` conditions in your `JOIN` to restrict the amount of data pulled into the initial data set. For instance, your first `JOIN` could be re-written like this:

```
INNER JOIN [MYDB].[dbo].[delivery] AS b
ON 
  a.[item_no] = b.[item_no]
  AND 
  b.[date] BETWEEN '2018-10-14' AND '2018-10-15'
```

With `INNER JOIN`, there's not much (any) difference between putting the filtering criteria in the `JOIN` or in a `WHERE`, but with `OUTER JOIN`, the results can, and will, be dramatically different, so it's important to understand what each component in the `SELECT` statement does, and when it does it.

Since all of your joins are `INNER`, your query could actually be written without a `WHERE` clause at all, like this:

```
SELECT a.[ID]
  ,a.[item_no]
  ,a.[qty]
FROM 
  [MYDB].[dbo].[details] AS a
INNER JOIN 
  [MYDB].[dbo].[delivery] AS b
  ON 
    a.[item_no] = b.[item_no]
    AND
    b.[destination] = 'my destination'
    AND 
    b.[date] BETWEEN '2018-10-14' AND '2018-10-15' 
  INNER JOIN [MYDB].[dbo].[options] AS c
  ON 
    a.[number] = c.[number] 
    AND
    a.[item_no] = c.[item_no]
```

On systems that are light on memory, filtering in the `ON` clause can reduce memory pressure, and I've used them that way, but most people find `WHERE` clauses to be more readable, since that's where we usually look for data filters.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining this it makes a lot of sense now thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 6):

Try below

```
SELECT a.[ID]
      ,a.[item_no]
      ,a.[qty]
  FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[details] AS a


  INNER JOIN [MYDB].[dbo].[delivery] AS b
  ON a.[item_no] = b.[item_no]
  INNER JOIN [MYDB].[dbo].[options] AS c
  ON a.[number] = c.[number] 
  and a.[item_no] = c.[item_no]

WHERE b.[destination] = 'my destination'
AND b.[date] BETWEEN '2018-10-14' AND '2018-10-15'
```

Comment: To add another condition to a `JOIN` you use an `AND`. This is not always the same as adding to the `WHERE`, so be careful

Answer (score 3):

Only one `where` clause per query.  This should be what you want to do:

```
SELECT d.[ID], d.[item_no], d.[qty]
FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[details] d JOIN
     MYDB].[dbo].[delivery] dv
     ON d.[item_no] = dv.[item_no] JOIN
     [MYDB].[dbo].[options] o
     ON d.[number] = o.[number] AND d.[item_no] = o.[item_no]
WHERE dv.[destination] = 'my destination' AND
      dv.[date] BETWEEN '2018-10-14' AND '2018-10-15' ;
```

You will note that I changed the table aliases to table abbreviations.  Meaningful table aliases make a query easier to read and maintain.

The condition in the first `WHERE` clause is a `JOIN` condition.  It really belongs in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Use `AND` instead of `WHERE` in JOIN statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `WHERE` clause  & move `a.[item_no] = c.[item_no]` with `ON` clause :

```
SELECT a.[ID], a.[item_no], a.[qty]
FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[details] AS a INNER JOIN 
     [MYDB].[dbo].[delivery] AS b
     ON a.[item_no] = b.[item_no] INNER JOIN 
     [MYDB].[dbo].[options] AS c 
     ON a.[number] = c.[number] AND a.[item_no] = c.[item_no]
WHERE b.[destination] = 'my destination' AND
      b.[date] BETWEEN '2018-10-14' AND '2018-10-15';
```

Answer (score 2):

if table has huge data and you want to apply join with other tables that will create performance problem, first filter data in sub query of table then apply join with other tables so that loop execution will be reduced while applying join with tables,for further detail you can check the execution plan and query process steps

```
  SELECT a.[ID]
   ,a.[item_no]
  ,a.[qty]
 FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[details] AS a


INNER JOIN (Select * from  [MYDB].[dbo].[delivery] 
WHERE [destination] = 'my destination'
AND [date] BETWEEN '2018-10-14' AND '2018-10-15' ) AS b
 ON a.[item_no] = b.[item_no]
INNER JOIN [MYDB].[dbo].[options] AS c
ON a.[number] = c.[number] 
and a.[item_no] = c.[item_no]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to extend existing **WHERE** clause.

```
SELECT a.[ID]
      ,a.[item_no]
      ,a.[qty]
  FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[details] AS a
  INNER JOIN [MYDB].[dbo].[delivery] AS b
  ON a.[item_no] = b.[item_no]
  INNER JOIN [MYDB].[dbo].[options] AS c
  ON a.[number] = c.[number] 
  WHERE a.[item_no] = c.[item_no] AND b.[destination] = 'my destination'
AND b.[date] BETWEEN '2018-10-14' AND '2018-10-15'
```